# CLIPS: Printing a slot value from a template of facts?

Tags: clips

We have to go through a list of people and print out "name has blue-eyes" if the person on the list has blue eyes.
We got it to print 3 times, since 3 people on the list have blue-eyes, but we can't figure out how to access the first-name variable slot of the fact.

Here's the code so far:

```
(deftemplate person (slot first-name) (slot eye-color)(slot hair-color) 
(slot hgt) (slot wgt)
)

(deffacts some-people "people involved"
     (person (first-name kevin) (eye-color blue) (hgt 175) (wgt 93))
     (person (first-name john) (eye-color brown) (hgt 190) (wgt 80))
     (person (first-name smith) (eye-color hazel) (hgt 165) (wgt 75))
     (person (first-name tom) (eye-color brown) (hgt 172) (wgt 77))
     (person (first-name alan) (eye-color blue) (hgt 190) (wgt 83)) 
     (person (first-name patricia) (eye-color blue) (hgt 175) (wgt 55))
     (person (first-name Leena) (eye-color brown) (hgt 176) (wgt 60))
     (person (first-name michael) (eye-color hazel) (hgt 190) (wgt 88))
     (person (first-name robert) (eye-color grey) (hgt 170) (wgt 77))
     (person (first-name judy) (eye-color hazel) (hgt 170) (wgt 76))
)

(defrule blueEyes "Print people with blue eyes"
 (person (eye-color blue))
 =>
 (printout t ??whatgoeshere?? " has-blue-eyes" crlf))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
(defrule blueEyes "Print people with blue eyes"
  (person (first-name ?name) (eye-color blue))
  =>
  (printout t ?name " has blue eyes" crlf))
```